# Python raw_input for file writing

Tags: python, file, raw-input

I have the following code:

```
print "We're going to write to a file you'll be prompted for"
targetfile = raw_input('Enter a filename: ')
targetfilefound = open('targetfile' , 'w')
print "What do we write in this file?"
targetfilefound.write("hello this is working!")
targetfilefound.close()
```

The script I'm creating should be able to write to a file that the user defines via raw_input. The above could be faulty at core, open to suggestions.

Comment: `'targetfile'` is not the same as `targetfile`

Comment: Remove the quotes from the variable `targetfile` like this `targetfilefound = open(targetfile , 'w')`

Comment: Thank you both, this has rectified the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the stuff the script is printing you probably want the user to input what should be printed to the file so:

```
print "We're going to write to a file you'll be prompted for"
targetfile = raw_input('Enter a filename: ')
targetfilefound = open(targetfile , 'w')
print "What do we write in this file?"
targetfilefound.write(raw_input())
targetfilefound.close()
```

Note: This method will create the new file if it does not exist. If you want to check whether the file exists you can use the os module, something like this:

```
import os

print "We're going to write to a file you'll be prompted for"
targetfile = raw_input('Enter a filename: ')
if os.path.isfile(targetfile) == True:
    targetfilefound = open(targetfile , 'w')
    print "What do we write in this file?"
    targetfilefound.write(raw_input())
    targetfilefound.close()
else:
    print "File does not exist, do you want to create it? (Y/n)"
    action = raw_input('> ')
    if action == 'Y' or action == 'y':
        targetfilefound = open(targetfile , 'w')
        print "What do we write in this file?"
        targetfilefound.write(raw_input())
        targetfilefound.close()
    else:
        print "No action taken"
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by others, remove the quotes from target file as you have assigned it already to a variable.

But actually instead of writing as code you can use the with open as given below

```
with open('somefile.txt', 'a') as the_file:
    the_file.write('hello this is working!\n')
```

In the above case, you don't need to do any exception handling while processing the file. When-ever an error occurs the file cursor object is automatically closed and we dont need to explicitly close it. Even it writing to file it success, it will automatically close the file pointer reference.

[Explanation of efficient use of with from Pershing Programming blog](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/)

Comment: nick064, if you like the answer can you please vote for it